# Заполнить массив по кругу

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

int const n = 10;
int A[n][n];
int i = 1, j, k, p = n / 2;
for (k = 1; k <= p; k++)
{
    for (j = k - 1; j < n - k + 1; j++) A[k - 1][j] = i++;
    for (j = k; j < n - k + 1; j++) A[j][n - k] = i++;
    for (j = n - k - 1; j >= k - 1; --j) A[n - k][j] = i++;
    for (j = n - k - 1; j >= k; j--) A[j][k - 1] = i++;
}
if (n % 2 == 1) A[p][p] = n * n;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
            if (j == n - 1) cout << "\n";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот здесь заполнено, но не в нужную сторону, помогите развернуть пожалуйста, очень срочно требуется(((

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int arr[N][N];
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // левая грань
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i][0] = cnt++;
    }

    // нижняя грань
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[N - 1][i] = cnt++;
    }

    // правая грань
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        arr[i][N - 1] = cnt++;
    }

    // верхняя грань
    for (int i = N - 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        arr[0][i] = cnt++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";

            if (j == N - 1) 
            {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```